# Why is '.' a reserved character in MarkdownV2 in Telegram's Bot API?

Tags: escaping, markdown, telegram, telegram-bot

As of Telegram's Bot API version 4.5, the API supports a new text format, [`MarkdownV2`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdownv2-style). This is an enhanced version of the previous Markdown support.

The ["specification" for MarkdownV2](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdownv2-style) says:

> - Inside `(...)` part of inline link definition, all ')' and '\' must be escaped with a preceding '\' character.
> - In all other places characters '_', '*', '[', ']', '(', ')', '~', '`', '>', '#', '+', '-', '=', '|', '{', '}', '.', '!' must be escaped with the preceding character '\'.

Why does the dot `.` character need to be escaped? As far as I can see, it isn't used in any formatting syntax. The syntax examples that Telegram provides certainly doesn't use `.` in that way:

> To use this mode, pass *MarkdownV2* in the *parse_mode* field. Use the following syntax in your message:
>
> ````
> *bold \*text*
> _italic \*text_
> __underline__
> ~strikethrough~
> *bold _italic bold ~italic bold strikethrough~ __underline italic bold___ bold*
> [inline URL](http://www.example.com/)
> [inline mention of a user](tg://user?id=123456789)
> `inline fixed-width code`
> ```
> pre-formatted fixed-width code block
> ```
> ```python
> pre-formatted fixed-width code block written in the Python programming language
> ```
> ````

Comment: A better question would be "Why can't telegram use a decent Markdown library instead of this escape everything manually.  Sort of defeats the purpose of Markdown.....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know about Telegram specifically, but Markdown uses `.` as part of ordered lists, e.g.:

```
1. One
1. Two
1. Three
```

which renders as:

1. One
2. Two
3. Three

Note that in the original spec the number used doesn't matter; Markdown renumbers for you.

In contrast,

```
1\. One
1\. Two
1\. Three
```

renders as

1. One
1. Two
1. Three